# Git merge single file without rebasing

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-rebase

I have three branches (let's call them master, testing, and feature). All three are shared, so I cannot rebase any of them without causing problems for others. Currently, all three branches have diverged (none is a fast-forward), so eventually some merging will need to done, since rebasing is not an option.

For the moment, though, I would like to pull in the Makefile from testing into feature, since  feature was split off from master, and the Makefile was added in testing. I do *not* want to merge in any other changes between the two branches, however.

My understanding is that if I just git-add Makefile to feature, this will cause merge conflicts when I merge feature back into testing (and then master), especially if I make any further additions to the Makefile in my feature branch.

I could do git-cherry-pick; however, there were multiple commits to the Makefile in testing, and I assume there's a better way than trying to cherry-pick all of those commits into feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just do a

`git checkout branch_name <path(s)>`

This can load a specific file but you can also use wildcards and directories

Note that:

- Paths are relative
- The path makes that git does not switch branches, so you can just commit after gettihg the file

Comment: Wow - I've used checkout both for switching to a commit by it's SHA, and on a file revert back to HEAD, but I didn't realize that you could combine the two that way. This is rather obvious in retrospect now, but thanks!